# what should java.testMethod be set to for vscode to run junit tests

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code

vscode 1.52 redhat 7.7

I believe I have all the extensions I need installed ( although the maven extension failed to install it looks like the pom file was read ). When I open a junit test case I see "run all Tests". When I select it I get an error

set "java.testMethod"" in ./vscode/settings.json

I've searched the web and the vscode documentation but am not finding a reference to java.testMethod so I don't have any idea what to set it to. I am also puzzled that it refers to .vscode/settings.json when that file is under .config/Code/User

Comment: Can you show me how to reproduce your error?

Comment: I just did an install, git clone of my repository and went to one of my junit test cases. Selected run all Tests and got the error. I've had a lot of configuration issues, still can't get a java class to run, the output window suggests its trying to connect to a server somewhere (185.199.110.133) even though I have the launch.json request set to launch.

Comment: You said `I've had a lot of configuration issues, still can't get a java class to run`, please follow the [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) to check your java environment.  About `the output window suggests its trying to connect to a server somewhere (185.199.110.133)`, can you share your code and are you going on some remote testing?

Comment: I upgraded to 1.59-insiders version and things are working as expected. I don't think all of the extensions installed properly on 1.52.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem. And it was solved. The reason is that the class did not import the reference. You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Had very similar issue and it turns out finally that some extensions which I unconsciously installed were fine by the time there was an update.After reintsalling only needed extensions all went back to working mode.Be sure the Test Runner for java (should be in Extension Pack for Java) is enabled.